# Hide sheet not working using ClosedXML library

Tags: c#

```
XLWorkbook wb = null;    
            IXLWorksheet ws = null;    
            String currentDateTimeDirPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");    
            if (!Directory.Exists(currentDateTimeDirPath))    
            {    
                Directory.CreateDirectory(currentDateTimeDirPath);    
            }    
            string strFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yy.HHmmsss") + ".xlsx";    
            string strFilePath = currentDateTimeDirPath + @"\" + strFileName;    
            wb = new XLWorkbook();    
            wb.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");    
            ws = wb.Worksheets.First();    
            ws.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Hello there 1111111";    
            ws.Hide(); //Not hiding worksheet     
            ws.CollapseRows(); //Not Collapsing rows    
            ws.CollapseColumns(); //Not collapsing columns     
            ws.Protect("12345678");     
            wb.SaveAs(strFilePath);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find the method `Hide()`.
But you can use the property `Visible` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetclass.visible?view=excel-pia)

Comment: I tried Visible property, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Anyway I'm not sure the ClosedXML library provide any display of the Excel Workbook.
I've tested it on a sample app and everything seems to work. When trying this on Excel, Excel display a message "A workbook must contain at least one visible worksheet. To hide, delete, or move the selected sheet(s), you must first insert a new sheet or unhide a sheet that is already hidden". 
So in your code add 2 sheets, and hide the first.
So if you open Excel after you should see the second worksheet, and the first would be hidden.